# Does samba need to fetch the entire file to determine its size?

Tags: samba, cifs

Given the following configuration:

- server with samba version 4.7.6-ubuntu
- client mounts a samba share using `mount -t cifs`

If a `du -h /shared/filename` command is executed on the client, will the client need to fetch the entire file from the server to determine its file size? What about `du --apparent-size`? What about a simple `ls -lR` operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know du uses the stat call and retrieves file metadata to provide file size. It doesn't actually check file length, unless you use the `-c` flag, then it actually counts bytes.

Therefore it shouldn't fetch the file.

`ls` does the same stat call.

`du --apparent-size` should transfer the whole file as it checks for sparse areas and such.

Answer (score 2):

### Such an operation will most certainly *not* read the file.

Both `du` and `ls` operate on file metadata retrieved by a variant of the stat() call only (in fact recent `ls` uses `lstat()` while `du` uses `fstatat()`). It doesn't matter what parameters you pass to `du` or `ls`. These tools will never handle the actual file-data.

I don't know any filesystem (there may be exceptions when it comes to esoteric filesystem implementations with fuse) that reads the actual file to retrieve this metadata.